# Help on viewing a seemingly deleted answer on a marked off-topic post?

Tags: support, off-topic, help

I asked a question in the physics stackexchange about the fastest ramp ending velocity for science project and it got one answer before it was marked off-topic for being too similar to a homework problem. I apologize for this and don't plan to fill up the site more things like that but I would really like to see and save the answer to it so I could actually use it. I searched around and saw that users with high reputation can view deleted answers. Would it be possible for you guys to see the removed answer to [Fastest ending velocity ramp with varying height?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511519/fastest-ending-velocity-ramp-with-varying-height) and screenshot it in an answer?

Comment: As this question is about a situation on *one specific site* in the Stack Exchange network, unfortunately, we have to mark this question as "off-topic" for this site. Each site has a *per-site meta* where you can ask questions about that site, which can be accessed through the site switcher on the top right corner. Questions on this site, Meta Stack Exchange, are expected to relate to the entire SE network as a whole, not just one specific site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should not be shown. It was probably deleted as a violation of Phys.SE policy, and the message the moderators and high reputation users of the site is that such answers which help people solve problems from off-topic questions should not be permitted, since they encourage people to continue asking these questions.

For more information, please ask a question on the Phys.SE meta site, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/. Users on the site you're presently on are unlikely to have the ability to view deleted posts on Phys.SE, and they may not have information regarding the policies. A post on Phys.SE's meta site will also be more likely to draw a response from the user who deleted the answer.

Per [this recent update on Phys.SE meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12448), the close banner on future questions closed under this policy will reflect that the answers may be deleted.

If it was deleted by the author, you should not want to see the answer, since it is likely to be incorrect or it may have some other critical flaw.